# How hard is it to convert manual column shifter to manual floor shifter?

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, diy, shifter

I am planning to buy a Ford Taunus P7B 17M but it has a 4 speed column shifter. Most of the P7B models came with a 4 speed floor shifter. Both are exactly the same transmission only difference is their shift actuation method, on some its column shifter and on most its a floor shifter so parts already exist to make it floor shifter. I am wondering if the labor part of the job would be hard? Also below are pictures you can see column shifter and the floor shifter versions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. column shifter?  I would imagine that having a column shift would make the car way more valued than a floor shift model.  What will this car be used for?  Daily driver or cool collector's item?

Comment: @zipzit Im gonna use the car as my daily driver, its got a 1.7L Köln V4 engine with around 75 net hp. Only the cheapest trim of the Taunus 17m P7Bs came with a column shifter which is why most of the 17m and all of the 20m P7Bs came with floor shifters. Column shifter models go for less than floor shifter ones since they are the lowest trim.